# Multiple User Types - Group Authentication - Devise Token Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, access-token

I am using the Devise Token Auth gem (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) with multiple users, and am getting a weird bug when trying to authenticate. I create a `devise_token_auth_group` that lets me authenticate multiple user types. However, neither of the `if` or `elsif` conditions below are met, although the `before_action :authenticate_user!` seems to pass for the index action (because it doesn't render or redirect and allows the index action to run). Any ideas if I am doing this wrong or missing something?

I am signed in as a shopper and should be getting all locations when i send a request to this action. At first, I get all locations. However, after repeatedly accessing the server every 5 seconds, `@locations` ends up being empty because neither the `if` or `elsif` conditions are met... This leads me to believe the before action is not working properly. As a test, I tried just hitting this route using PostMan Rest Client without any access token, and somehow it returned an empty array, so I believe that is where the problem is.

```
devise_token_auth_group :user, contains: [:shopper, :merchant]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:update]
before_action :authenticate_merchant!, only: [:update]

def index
    if merchant_signed_in?
        @locations = Location.where(merchant_company_id: params[:merchant_company_id])
    elsif shopper_signed_in?
        @locations = Location.all
    end

    # the @locations variable sometimes has all locations (as expected)
    # but after a bunch of sequential requests, it is empty so the action renders "null"
    render json: @locations, status: 200
end
```

Comment: Can you tell me if the `user_signed_in?` function returns true? And if you can access to the `current_user` devise helper ?

Comment: unfortunately, `current_user` is `nil`, and `user_signed_in?` returns false, but i was very hopeful when seeing your suggestion below. Is it possible that those methods in the link you included are not being swizzled properly?

Also, it seems that this may be related to the batch request throttle?

Comment: I believe this indeed has to do with the batch request, and this is the issue on GitHub that is related: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/188

Additionally, if you access this route, and do not provide an access token, you should get a 401 Unauthorized because `before_action :authenticate_user!` should render or redirect. Instead as described in the OP, it returns an empty array (`@locations`)

Comment: Can you try to remove the line containing the `devise_token_auth_group`, i think we don't need it anymore with the code in the answer. And remove the `:authenticate_merchant!` before_action. It will normally work.

Answer (score 1):

For the `index` action, you call the `:authenticate_user!` helper, so, in this action, you can access to the `user_signed_in?` and `current_user` helpers, generated from your `authenticate_user!` call.

According to [this part of the gem code](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/a561a9b74bd8f6eb957bc54a5ee3aa3714bcfc8e/lib/devise_token_auth/controllers/helpers.rb#L12), we can read that the `authenticate_XXX!`, `XXX_signed_in` and `current_XXX` are generated with your `devise_token_auth_group` as XXX, so `user`.

In this case, you can only access helpers generated by your `devise_token_auth_group` name as:

- `authenticate_user!`
- `user_signed_in?`
- `current_user`
- `current_users`

A good way to change your code is like this:

```
devise_token_auth_group :user, contains: [:shopper, :merchant]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:update]
before_action :authenticate_merchant!, only: [:update]

def index
    if current_user.is_a? Shopper
        @locations = Location.where(merchant_company_id: params[:merchant_company_id])
    elsif current_user.is_a? Merchant
        @locations = Location.all
    end

    # the @locations variable sometimes has all locations (as expected)
    # but after a bunch of sequential requests, it is empty so the action renders "null"
    render json: @locations, status: 200
end
```

[More documentation here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#methods)